# Access IBOutlet from customCell into ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have a collectionView inside a tableView cell and i would like to call the collectionView outlet to update my UI by reloading it. I have tried different ways and getting crashes about being nil. Is there anyway i can do this?

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!   
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let identifier = "cell"

    var data = [CKRecord]()

    var sections = [customCollectionModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sections = customCollectionModel.createSectionsArray()
        fetchDataFromCloud()
    }

    func fetchDataFromCloud() {
        books = [CKRecord]()
        books.removeAll()
       // Reload CollectionView here

        let container = CKContainer.default()
        let publicDatabase = container.publicCloudDatabase
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Book", predicate: predicate)
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

        let operation = CKQueryOperation(query: query)
        operation.desiredKeys = ["image"]
        operation.queuePriority = .veryHigh
        operation.resultsLimit = 25
        operation.recordFetchedBlock = { (record) -> Void in
            self.data.append(record)
        }
        operation.queryCompletionBlock = { (cursor, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Download failed \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            print("Download Successful")

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            // reload collectionView here
            }
        }
        operation.qualityOfService = .userInteractive

        publicDatabase.add(operation)
    }
```

Comment: Is the collectionview in the prototype table cell? If so, did you connect it to the IBOutlet?  If so, show the exact line that the nil access happens on.

Comment: @LouFranco everything connected well, nil come when i either use `var viewController = ViewController()` then use var to do `self.viewController.collectionView.reloadData`

Answer (score 0):

When you construct a view controller like this:

```
var viewController = ViewController()
```

The outlets are not connected yet (and are nil) -- they get connected at view load time and then `viewDidLoad` is called.  In this function (or any time later), the outlets will not be nil.

Comment: i have also tried that, problem is how can use that var in `viewDidLoad` to call the collectionViewOutlet . Its already a local var and cant access it in my `fetchDataFromCloud` method

Comment: in the queryCompletionBlock reload the table cell that contains the collection view.